# Boost Asio Sync vs Async

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, synchronization, boost-asio

I use Boost Asio for the first time and I'm having a application that accepts multiple connections, each in separate threads and read/write data to a single tcp socket.

My understanding of sync method is that every thread before using the fd, they need to make sure that it's free using a call like `select()/WSAEventSelect()`, `WaitForSingleObject()`.

So sync method has this waiting for the resource to become available to it.

But what about async method?

Let's say I have a socket and doing `async_accept()` for accepting connections, `async_read()` for receiving and `async_write()` for sending. Since in async method the resource/socket is not kept, do I still need to wait for it to become available?

In the beginning of this question I explained what I'm trying to do, so please forgive if my understanding of the problem an what came next is not accurate.

Thanks for understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most of your explanation is sadly upside down. Picking out the most obvious ones:

> My understanding of sync method is that every thread before using the fd, they need to make sure that it's free using a call like `select()`/`WSAEventSelect()`, `WaitForSingleObject()`.

On the contrary, `select` (poll/epoll) are useful for *asynchronous* handling of events (like incoming data available or error condition). They are not used/useful for synchronous operations, because they will just block until the state is reached.

Maybe you're *imagining* that the kernel implements that "as if" synchronizing with a thread synchronization primitive. Fair enough, though probably not very accurate, the effect is that: the call blocks.

This style of communication is limited even with a thread-per-connection as it will never allow full-duplex communication, which means some protocols are prone to deadlocks.

> Let's say I have a socket and doing `async_accept()` for accepting connections, `async_read()` for receiving and `async_write()` for sending. Since in async method the resource/socket is not kept, do I still need to wait for it to become available?

Yes and no. If you were doing asynchronous BSD sockets by hand, YES, you would actually need to poll for socket events, like mentioned above.

The whole purpose of Asio is to make this transparent in a platform-independent way, while also leveraging a boat load of good practices and optimizations. Therefore, ***NO*** you don't need to wait for [the socket] to become available.

> Since in async method the resource/socket is not kept

But it is. It is kept by the service implementation which lives in the execution context (`io_context`). The `tcp::socket` (or other `basic_stream_socket` instance) is your "handle". So the socket is kept and the service knows when/how to wait for low-level states/events.

I could give you an example of how I'd implement what you describe, but I have a lot of answers on this site that already show. If you have more specific questions, you're welcome to ask them.

Comment: So, in case of Boost Asio, each thread can just async_write() and async_read() without worry for the resource being busy, as Asio makes that part transparent?

Comment: It's hard to answer this without clear code to refer to (as it stands, "the resource" is unspecified). But yeah. especially if you make a single-threaded server to handle concurrent connections this is completely transparent. Only if you have dependencies between different sessions (logical "threads") or have full-duplex operations in a situation where there is more than one IO thread you will use `strand`s to make sure access is properly serialized.

Comment: I quote from the question, "accepts multiple connections, each in separate threads and read/write data to a single tcp socket." So I cannot have single threaded as I need to accept different connections, get their request, send it over the network and return the response back to them. So I don't think I can achieve that with a single threaded application, right?

Comment: You can, but you choose not to. That's a valid option, which is why I added the mention of a strands. Mind you, you still may not need them, but we still don't see any actual code, so I think it is almost useless to discuss. Information about the library removed from application is already available in docs and examples. Feel free to browse my examples on the site.

Comment: For fun, here's the simplest implementation I can think of of what you describe. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e17518e3a3850f7 It handles many connections concurrently and does so all on a single thread. The point is that async operations do not block so the context can service all other connections and the acceptor. Here's a more interactive demo locally: https://imgur.com/a/mFybVna

Comment: Today I'm taking a close look at the sample code you provided. My final goal is to write HTTP tunnel. So I need to accept multiple TCP connections and convert them to HTTP and send them over.
So each of those connections will be constantly sending and receiving data. In the sample code that you provided you are using coroutines, is this the right way of implementing this?

Comment: There is no right way. Asio supports completion tokens, which lets you choose the completion mechanism. Coroutines are one example, and I think it's often by far the simplest if you can use c++. Also I think a proxy server is very close to what you need. I've shown working proxies (both HTTP and not) on this site before. A simple HTTP proxy in principe works to tunnel other protocols already

Comment: Can you link me to the working proxy you are talking about?
I was reading about `coroutine` right after looking at your sample code, it seem spawning new coroutine will stop the already running one, so If that is true, when I want to proxy multiple TCP connections that read and write at the same time will make chaos if one can cause running coroutine to stop.

Comment: Did you look at my example - with the interactive demo, demonstrating just that? Coroutines are studied while they await asynchronous operations. In IO bound applications that is 99%+ of the time so nothing is "stopped" any more than with loads of threads and blocking operations

Comment: "studied" should have been "suspended". Darn phone keyboards

Comment: `async_read_until` doesn't seem ideal for raw/binary data, what do you suggest for that use case?

Comment: It does seem ideal for binary data. What you probably mean is that you have unframed data. In that case use `async_read_some`

Comment: I modified the sample code provided here and ran into some issue and wanted to improve it by unfortunately failed and asked as a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/137267803?noredirect=1

Comment: @Jelal I added a working implementation of your described goal, I hope that helps. Also, it became clear to me that you don't know coroutines (you probably didn't know what `co_await` does). In that case, consider *not* using them. Then you get callbacks all over the place: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bb7e20e9acf411d I hope you see why I think flow-control and lifetime management is a lot simpler in the case of coroutines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256657/discussion-between-jelal-and-sehe).