# Boost asio async_read_some and reading whole data

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I recently asked a question about Boost Asio and got an interesting suggestion from one of the members https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e17518e3a3850f7.

It uses `async_read_until` and it reads until the appearance of '\n', which works fine if you are reading unformatted data, it's not the best option.

I learned that `async_read_some()` is what should be used, so after searching online, seeing some sample code, I tried to reproduce the same result but with `async_read_some()`.

Below is my sample code, but unfortunately my try got failed,

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>



namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace this_coro = asio::this_coro;
using asio::ip::tcp;



template <typename T> using Defer = asio::deferred_t::as_default_on_t<T>;
using Socket = Defer<tcp::socket>;
using Acceptor = Defer<tcp::acceptor>;

void handler(
    const boost::system::error_code& error, // Result of operation.
    std::size_t bytes_transferred           // Number of bytes read.
)
{
    std::cout << bytes_transferred << std::endl;
    return;
}

asio::awaitable<void> session(Socket socket)
{
    auto ep = socket.remote_endpoint();
    std::cout << "New session for " << ep << "\n";

    size_t requests_handled = 0;
    for (std::string buf;; ++requests_handled)
    {
        char data[32] = { 0 };
        socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data, sizeof(data)), handler);

    }
    std::cout << " -- Session " << ep << " handled " << requests_handled << " requests" << std::endl;
}

asio::awaitable<void> listener(uint16_t port)
{
    auto ex = co_await this_coro::executor;
    Acceptor acc(ex, { {}, port });
    for (;;)
    {
        co_spawn(ex, session(co_await acc.async_accept()), asio::detached);
    }
}

int main()
{
    asio::io_context ioc(1);
    co_spawn(ioc, listener(8989), asio::detached);

    ioc.run(); // single threaded, everything on main thread
}
```

- I couldn't read any data from the socket
- My completion handler never got called

Aside from how I broke the working example, I was also wondering how can I read the whole incoming data, the size of the incoming data is vary, what is the best way to read all the incoming data over the tcp socket?

I'm new to Boost Asio and C++, I tried my best to find the solution myself, but unfortunately didn't have any success in getting the same result as `async_read_until` and reading all the vary size incoming tcp packets.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use a local array as an async buffer, it'll be destroyed before the data gets written into it and the completion handler will write over a random bit of your stack, use the `std::string` buffer as in the original code

Comment: @AlanBirtles In this case I think the lifetime was fine, but an attempt to await the operation on the coro was flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to handle the output of the read in call-back style? That makes no sense when you have a coroutine already. Just use `asio::deferred` that was already the default completion token:

```
 co_await socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data, sizeof(data)));
```

This way, since the completion is now guaranteed to be a resumption of the coroutine, the lifetime of the array is not an issue, as the coroutine owns the stack frame.

### BONUS

To save you a bit of time, here's my own adaptation to implement what you described in the [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77851682/boost-asio-sync-vs-async/77851970?noredirect=1#comment137260831_77851970):

> My final goal is to write HTTP tunnel. So I need to accept multiple
> TCP connections and convert them to HTTP and send them over. So each
> of those connections will be constantly sending and receiving data.

I'll use `tinyproxy -d -c test.cfg` to test, test.cfg:

```
Port 8888
Listen 127.0.0.1
Timeout 600
Allow 127.0.0.1
```

Code

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
namespace json = boost::json;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace this_coro = asio::this_coro;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;

#include <iostream>
#include <syncstream>

static auto out() { return std::osyncstream(std::cout); }

struct Config {
    struct Endpoint {
        std::string host = "0.0.0.0";
        uint16_t    port;

        operator tcp::endpoint() const {
            using asio::ip::address;
            return {address::from_string(host.empty() ? "0.0.0.0" : host), port};
        }
    };
    struct Tunnel {
        tcp::endpoint listen_endpoint;
        std::string   remote;
    };

    tcp::endpoint       proxy_endpoint;
    std::vector<Tunnel> tunnels;

    // for JSON settings parsing
    friend Endpoint tag_invoke(json::value_to_tag<Endpoint>, json::value const& jv) {
        return {value_to<std::string>(defaulted(jv, "host", "0.0.0.0")),
                value_to<uint16_t>(defaulted(jv, "port", 80))};
    }
    friend Tunnel tag_invoke(json::value_to_tag<Tunnel>, json::value const& jv) {
        return {value_to<Endpoint>(jv.at("listen_endpoint")), value_to<std::string>(jv.at("remote"))};
    }
    static json::value defaulted(json::value const& jv, std::string_view key, auto _default) {
        auto v = jv.as_object().if_contains(key);
        return v ? *v : std::move(_default);
    };

    friend Config tag_invoke(json::value_to_tag<Config>, json::value const& jv) {
        return {value_to<Endpoint>(jv.at("proxy_endpoint")), value_to<std::vector<Tunnel>>(jv.at("tunnels"))};
    }
};


struct Server {
    Server(json::value settings) : cfg_(value_to<Config>(settings)) { }

    void start(asio::any_io_executor ex) {
        for (auto& tun : cfg_.tunnels)
            asio::co_spawn(ex, listener(tun), asio::detached);
    }

  private:
    template <typename T> using Defer = asio::deferred_t::as_default_on_t<T>;
    using Socket                      = Defer<tcp::socket>;
    using Acceptor                    = Defer<tcp::acceptor>;

    asio::awaitable<void> session(Socket downstream, std::string remote) try {
        namespace http = boost::beast::http;

        auto ex    = co_await this_coro::executor;
        auto ep    = downstream.remote_endpoint();
        out() << "New session for " << ep << std::endl;

        // connect to upstream
        Socket upstream(ex);
        tcp::endpoint proxy = cfg_.proxy_endpoint;
        co_await upstream.async_connect(cfg_.proxy_endpoint);

        downstream.set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));
        upstream.set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));

        {
            http::request<http::empty_body> req(http::verb::connect, remote, 10);
            req.set(http::field::host, remote);
            out() << "Trying to connect to proxy at " << proxy << ": " << req << std::endl;
            co_await async_write(upstream, req);
        }

        asio::streambuf buf_up, buf_down;

        {
            http::response_parser<http::string_body> p;
            p.eager(false);
            co_await http::async_read_header(upstream, buf_up, p);

            auto response = p.release();

            // out() << "Proxy response " << response.base() << std::endl;
            out() << "Session " << ep << ": " << response.reason() << std::endl;
            if (response.result() != http::status::ok)
                co_return;
        }

        std::atomic_size_t transferred = 0;

        auto pump = [=, &transferred](Socket& from, Socket& to,
                                      asio::streambuf& buf) -> asio::awaitable<void> {
            auto dir = from.remote_endpoint() == proxy ? "DOWN" : "UP  ";
            out() << "pump " << dir << std::endl;

            for (error_code ec; !ec;) {
                auto token = redirect_error(asio::deferred, ec);

                auto n = co_await from.async_read_some(buf.prepare(1024), token);
                buf.commit(n);
                /*
                 *out() << "TRACE " << dir
                 *          << quoted(std::string_view(buffer_cast<char const*>(buf.data()), buf.size()))
                 *          << std::endl;
                 */

                auto eof = ec == asio::error::eof;
                if (buf.size() && (eof || !ec)) {
                    auto n = co_await async_write(to, buf, token);
                    transferred += n;
                    buf.consume(n);
                }
                if (ec) {
                    out() << "Session: " << ep << "/" << dir << " closing due to " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    to.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send);
                }
            }
            out() << "Session: " << ep << "/" << dir << " exit" << std::endl;
        };

        co_await (pump(upstream, downstream, buf_up) && pump(downstream, upstream, buf_down));

        out() << "Session " << ep << " total " << transferred << " bytes transferred" << std::endl;
    } catch(boost::system::system_error const& se) {
        out() << "Session exception: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
    }

    asio::awaitable<void> listener(Config::Tunnel const& tun) {
        auto ex = co_await this_coro::executor;
        auto& [ep, remote] = tun;
        out() << "Tunnel from " << ep << " to " << remote << " via " << cfg_.proxy_endpoint << std::endl;

        for (Acceptor acc(ex, ep);;)
            co_spawn(ex, session(co_await acc.async_accept(), remote), asio::detached);

        co_return;
    }

    Config cfg_;
};

int main() {
    Server server(json::parse(R"(
        {
            "proxy_endpoint": {
                "host": "127.0.0.1",
                "port": 8888
            },
            "tunnels": [{
                "listen_endpoint": {
                    "host": "",
                    "port": 9080
                },
                "remote": "example.com:80"
            }, {
                "listen_endpoint": {
                    "host": "",
                    "port": 9081
                },
                "remote": "google.com:443"
            }, {
                "listen_endpoint": {
                    "host": "",
                    "port": 9082
                },
                "remote": "localhost:8989"
            }]
        })"));

    asio::io_context ioc(1);
    server.start(ioc.get_executor());

    ioc.run(); // single threaded, everything on main thread
}
```

When started runs three tunnels:

```
Tunnel from 0.0.0.0:9080 to example.com:80 via 127.0.0.1:8888
Tunnel from 0.0.0.0:9081 to google.com:443 via 127.0.0.1:8888
Tunnel from 0.0.0.0:9082 to localhost:8989 via 127.0.0.1:8888
```

Then we can do some manual requests, like:

```
$ nc localhost 9080
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

Which will work. You can automate the same using wget or curl:

```
wget http://localhost:9080/ --header='Host: example.com:80'
curl --header 'Host: example.com'  'http://localhost:9080/'
```

Because the HTTP proxy gets out of the way straight after establishing the connection, the protocol may be binary, like for SSL:

```
curl -k --header 'Host: google.com' 'https://localhost:9081/search?q=qwerty'
```

See it all live demoed:

[image]

## BONUS 2: Without Coroutines

What if you don't have C++20. Or don't want to learn what all those `co_await`, `co_return`, `co_spawn` things mean?

In that case, consider *not* using them. Then you get callbacks all over the place.

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
namespace json = boost::json;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <syncstream>

static auto out() { return std::osyncstream(std::cout); }

struct Config {
    struct Endpoint {
        std::string host = "0.0.0.0";
        uint16_t    port;

        operator tcp::endpoint() const {
            using asio::ip::address;
            return {address::from_string(host.empty() ? "0.0.0.0" : host), port};
        }
    };
    struct Tunnel {
        tcp::endpoint listen_endpoint;
        std::string   remote;
    };

    tcp::endpoint       proxy_endpoint;
    std::vector<Tunnel> tunnels;

    // for JSON settings parsing
    friend Endpoint tag_invoke(json::value_to_tag<Endpoint>, json::value const& jv) {
        return {value_to<std::string>(defaulted(jv, "host", "0.0.0.0")),
                value_to<uint16_t>(defaulted(jv, "port", 80))};
    }
    friend Tunnel tag_invoke(json::value_to_tag<Tunnel>, json::value const& jv) {
        return {value_to<Endpoint>(jv.at("listen_endpoint")), value_to<std::string>(jv.at("remote"))};
    }
    static json::value defaulted(json::value const& jv, std::string_view key, auto _default) {
        auto v = jv.as_object().if_contains(key);
        return v ? *v : std::move(_default);
    };

    friend Config tag_invoke(json::value_to_tag<Config>, json::value const& jv) {
        return {value_to<Endpoint>(jv.at("proxy_endpoint")), value_to<std::vector<Tunnel>>(jv.at("tunnels"))};
    }
};

namespace Helpers {
    namespace http = boost::beast::http;
    static void check(error_code const& ec) {
        if (ec)
            throw boost::system::system_error(ec);
    }

    struct Session : std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
        Session(tcp::socket downstream, std::string remote, tcp::endpoint proxy_endpoint)
            : downstream_(std::move(downstream))
              , remote_(remote)
              , proxy_(proxy_endpoint) {}

        void start() {
            out() << "New session for " << my_ep << std::endl;
            start_connect();
        }

        ~Session() {
            out() << "Session " << my_ep << " total " << transferred << " bytes transferred" << std::endl;
        }

      private:
        tcp::socket   downstream_, upstream_{downstream_.get_executor()};
        tcp::endpoint my_ep = downstream_.remote_endpoint();
        std::string   remote_;
        tcp::endpoint proxy_;

        void start_connect() {
            // connect to upstream
            upstream_.async_connect(proxy_, [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec) {
                check(ec);
                downstream_.set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));
                upstream_.set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));

                start_proxy_connect();
            });
        }

        http::request<http::empty_body> req;
        asio::streambuf                 buf_up, buf_down;
        http::response_parser<http::string_body> p;

        void start_proxy_connect() {
            req = {http::verb::connect, remote_, 10};
            req.set(http::field::host, remote_);
            out() << "Trying to connect to proxy at " << proxy_ << ": " << req << std::endl;
            http::async_write(
                upstream_, req, [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t) {
                    check(ec);

                    p.eager(false);
                    http::async_read_header(
                        upstream_, buf_up, p, [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t) {
                            check(ec);
                            auto response = p.release();

                            // out() << "Proxy response " << response << std::endl;
                            out() << "Session " << my_ep << ": " << response.reason() << std::endl;
                            if (response.result() == http::status::ok)
                                start_proxy_loops();
                        });
                });
        }

        std::atomic_size_t transferred = 0;
        void pump(tcp::socket& from, tcp::socket& to, asio::streambuf& buf) {
            auto dir = from.remote_endpoint() == proxy_ ? "DOWN" : "UP  ";

            from.async_read_some(
                buf.prepare(1024),
                [this, self = shared_from_this(), &from, &to, &buf, dir](error_code ec, size_t n) {
                    buf.commit(n);
                    /*
                     *out() << "TRACE " << dir
                     *      << quoted(std::string_view(buffer_cast<char const*>(buf.data()), buf.size()))
                     *      << std::endl;
                     */

                    bool eof = ec == asio::error::eof;
                    if (ec) {
                        out() << "Session: " << my_ep << "/" << dir << " closing due to " << ec.message()
                              << std::endl;

                        if (!eof || !buf.size()) { // otherwise postpone till after relay of data
                            to.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send);
                        }
                    }

                    if (buf.size() && (eof || !ec)) {
                        async_write(to, buf, [this, self, eof, &from, &to, &buf](error_code ec, size_t n) {
                            if (!ec) {
                                transferred += n;
                                buf.consume(n);
                            }
                            if (ec || eof)
                                to.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send);
                            else
                                pump(from, to, buf);
                        });
                    }
                });
        }

        void start_proxy_loops() {
            pump(upstream_,   downstream_, buf_up) ;
            pump(downstream_, upstream_,   buf_down);
        }
    };

    struct Listener {
        Listener(asio::any_io_executor ex, Config::Tunnel const& cfg, tcp::endpoint proxy) : acc_{ex, cfg.listen_endpoint}, remote_(cfg.remote), proxy_(std::move(proxy)) {
            out() << "Tunnel from " << cfg.listen_endpoint << " to " << remote_ << " via " << proxy_ << std::endl;
            accept_loop();
        }

      private:
        void accept_loop() {
            acc_.async_accept([this](error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
                check(ec);
                std::make_shared<Helpers::Session>(std::move(s), remote_, proxy_)->start();
                accept_loop();
            });
        }

        tcp::acceptor acc_;
        std::string   remote_;
        tcp::endpoint proxy_;
    };
} // namespace Helpers

struct Server {
    Server(json::value settings) : cfg_(value_to<Config>(settings)) { }

    void start(asio::any_io_executor ex) {
        for (auto& tun : cfg_.tunnels)
            tunnels.emplace_back(ex, tun, cfg_.proxy_endpoint);
    }

  private:
    Config                       cfg_;
    std::list<Helpers::Listener> tunnels;
};

int main() {
    Server server(json::parse(R"(
        {
            "proxy_endpoint": {
                "host": "127.0.0.1",
                "port": 8888
            },
            "tunnels": [{
                "listen_endpoint": {
                    "host": "",
                    "port": 9080
                },
                "remote": "example.com:80"
            }, {
                "listen_endpoint": {
                    "host": "",
                    "port": 9081
                },
                "remote": "google.com:443"
            }, {
                "listen_endpoint": {
                    "host": "",
                    "port": 9082
                },
                "remote": "localhost:8989"
            }]
        })"));

    asio::io_context ioc(1);
    server.start(ioc.get_executor());

    ioc.run(); // single threaded, everything on main thread
}
```

I hope you see why I think flow-control and lifetime management is a lot simpler in the case of coroutines.

Comment: In case the coroutines were actually the confusing part, added a second BONUS take that doesn't use them. It has the added bonus of being c++11 compatible: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/6GPc5fMnn

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and especially the bonuses.